# Centering a <div> with a max-width, using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking for a way to center a div with a set max-width. I assumed I could do so by giving the div a max-width of 90% and an auto margin, then use jQuery to find and set a fixed width, which I hoped, the auto margin would then center for me.

Something like the following.

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $wrap = $('#wrap');

    $wrap.width($wrap.width());
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    max-width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
     <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/h/a/happy-smiley-face-icone-6672-96.png" />
     <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/h/a/happy-smiley-face-icone-6672-96.png" />
     <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/h/a/happy-smiley-face-icone-6672-96.png" />
     <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/h/a/happy-smiley-face-icone-6672-96.png" />
     <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/h/a/happy-smiley-face-icone-6672-96.png" />
</div><!-- end div id="wrap" -->
```

So basically, I wanna make a wrapper div that I can jam full of images, but will not exceed 90% screen width; take wrapper and center it. Is this possible? I understand my JQuery thinking is almost certainly wrong. I'm very new to it, but I assumed that Javascript is the way to go about this.

Comment: Won't it already work without the jQuery though? fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2TWa/

Comment: Based on the responses, your question is not entirely clear.  Your HTML and CSS alone center it.  You may be thinking of a different definition of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is curious, I figured out a JQuery way to do what I wanted.

I have a bunch of uniformly sized images that I want in a scale-able div which also has a 90% max-width. Here's what I came up with:

**JQuery:**

```
function divResize() {
var divWidth;
var extra;
divWidth = $(window).width() * .9;
extra  = divWidth % /*IMAGE SIZE IN PX*/;
divWidth = (divWidth - extra);
  $("#wrap").css({ width: divWidth });
}

$(document).ready(divResize);
$(window).resize(divResize);
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    margin:auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="/images.png" />
    <img src="/images.png" />
    <img src="/images.png" />
    <img src="/images.png" />
    <img src="/images.png" />
</div>
```

I guess my real problem was that I couldn't adequately explain my problem. Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript needed, everything is fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/RvLuE/

Answer (score 0):

What isn't working here? This works fine for me, but I don't think you need javascript?

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        body { }
        #wrap {max-width: 90%; margin: auto; background-color: red}
    </style>
    <div id='wrap'>a a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa aa a a a aa a<br/>a</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a possibly **short** row, set wrap's text-align to center, or make it display:inline-block if you have a border you need to show.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't think of that... Thanks a lot. Never been so glad to be reminded of my own stupidity.

Comment: On second thought, I realize I wanted my images to be left justified, so this wasn't quite a perfect answer.